# Unable to get rows count of an excel sheet using OfficeOpenXml.Core.ExcelPackage in c#

Tags: c#, .net-core

In my `.net core` web api project i want to get `rows` count. I installed the nuget package `OfficeOpenXml.Core.ExcelPackage` and using this code

```
using OfficeOpenXml.Core.ExcelPackage;


    public static async Task<List<ImportedFileData>> getFileData(IFormFile incomingFile) {
        var importedFileData = new List<ImportedFileData>();
        try
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await incomingFile.CopyToAsync(stream);

                using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
                    var rowCount = worksheet.WorksheetXml.XPathSelectElements("//d:sheetData/d:row", worksheet.NameSpaceManager).Count();
                    Console.WriteLine("===row count===");
                    Console.WriteLine(rowCount);

                }
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return importedFileData;
  }
```

Now when i try to get rows count using this code, so this error is printing on console

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.XmlException' in System.Private.Xml.dll
The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.
```

This is my excel file

[image]

Is there any thing i am missing?
How can i get rows count of the excel file?

Comment: If your file has data in it, then I would go with `worksheet.Cells`. And via the returned `ExcelRange` instance, you can access to the `Rows` property. Read: https://epplussoftware.com/docs/5.8/api/OfficeOpenXml.ExcelAddressBase.html#OfficeOpenXml_ExcelAddressBase_Rows

Comment: Is it an option for you to switch to using the more official [Open XML SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml) by Microsoft?

Comment: Can you please mention any example link of that?

Comment: Is `OfficeOpenXml.Core.ExcelPackage` from https://www.nuget.org/packages/OfficeOpenXml.Core.ExcelPackage/?  If so, do you know if there is any doc page or project website?

Comment: Also, might you please [edit] your question to give the **full `ToSTring()`** output of the exception, including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s), if any?  Because I think `OfficeOpenXml.Core.ExcelPackage` may just be broken.  When I try your code on a simple Excel doc I created, the getter for `Worksheets` throws the exception you see, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/VAJXnG.  It never even reaches your `XPathSelectElements()` call.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/OfficeOpenXml.Core.ExcelPackage/ hasn't been updated since 10/6/2016 and can't find a source code site for it.  The author https://github.com/joshcomley doesn't show it in is [public github repositories](https://github.com/joshcomley?tab=repositories&q=OfficeOpenXml&type=&language=&sort=).  it may just be dead, and broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [Open XML SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml) by Microsoft - [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/spreadsheets)

Consider an Excel file with a single sheet and below content.
Notice the row without data at row `3`.

[image]

---

You get the **number of rows having data ignoring the empty rows** via

```
worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().ChildElements.Count
```

This will return `3`.

---

You can get the **total number of rows including the empty ones** by parsing the
`SheetDimension.Reference` of a worksheet. This [`Reference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.sheetdimension.reference) property will contain a range like e.g. `A1:C4`.

The first part  `A1` represents the start column name and row number, the part after the colon `C4` is the end column name and row. We need that last number, here `4`.

Below code parses this reference via a regular expression.
*There might be better regular expressions to achieve the same.*

```
:[a-zA-z]+(?<nrOfRows>[0-9]+)
```

- `:` start from the colon character
- `[a-zA-z]+` followed by any a-z characters and upper cased variants.
- `(?<nrOfRows>` Start a named capture group named `nrOfRows` so that the upcoming numeric part/value can be retrieved later on
  using that name via `regex.Match(dimension).Groups["nrOfRows"].Value`
- `[0-9]+` followed by any numbers; this part holds the effective row number/index
- `)` end of the capture group

---

Full code

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

// Get your stream from somewhere
var stream = ...

using var document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, false);

var worksheet = document.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First().Worksheet;

var nrOfRowsWithData = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().ChildElements.Count;
Console.WriteLine(nrOfRowsWithData); // 3

var dimension = worksheet.SheetDimension.Reference; // A1:C4
// Note: there might be better regular expressions to achieve the same.
var regex = new Regex(":[a-zA-z]+(?<nrOfRows>[0-9]+)");
var nrOfRows = Convert.ToInt32(regex.Match(dimension).Groups["nrOfRows"].Value);
Console.WriteLine(nrOfRows); // 4
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more that what are you doing here in these 2 lines?

`var regex = new Regex(":[a-zA-z]*(?<nrOfRows>[0-9]*)");
var nrOfRows = Convert.ToInt32(regex.Match(dimension).Groups["nrOfRows"].Value);`